# How disable sound in Cefsharp Offscreen

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

How disable sound in Cefsharp Offscreen. In the official documentation did not find this information. A sound when the browser is annoying because like no program is open and there are alerts and other sounds.

Comment: You could try https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#mute-audio (I've not tested it). There is no `API` yet for that see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/173/mute-audio-in-the-browser-issue-1806/diff

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem. Than initialize Cef add argument:

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("mute-audio", "true");
```

Comment: Version `69.0.0` now has audio muted by default for `CefSharp.OffScreen`. Relevant commit is https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/e08e882c909f5559e8e42b015bc410415cd2666b#diff-2ecfdb174bf6b80d52f7840086accb73